# HMAC output of CVV

Tags: pci-dss

Would storing the output of a HMAC function with the PAN and CVV as input be considered PCI-DSS compliant ? This is post authorisation.

I suspect probably not as PCI-DSS explicitly forbids encrypting a CVV and storing that but a HMAC function is technically different.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea. The set of possible inputs is tiny. You could determine a CCV given its HMAC output and the key with negligible effort by using brute force.

You might not think that attacks from someone who knows the key are important. However, encryption has the same property. If the key is not disclosed, then it's possible to safely encrypt CVVs. If the key is ever leaked, however, then there's nothing protecting data.

If it's not against the literal interpreptation of the standard, then it's still against the spirit of the rule forbidding encryption.

It would also be a terrible to use a plain hash function, with or without salt...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the input would be a combination of PAN and CVV not the CVV alone. Totally agree the security hinges on how well the key is secured; the question was geared around how that would be viewed from a PCI compliance point of view rather that strictly a security angle. My gut feeling was that it would probably still be deemed as being non-compliant.

Comment: @RanjitMurali In general, I advise people to consider the hash of most kinds of data as if it were plaintext. That includes names, email addresses, street addresses, license plate numbers, social security numbers, etc. Everyone overestimates the cost of guess-and-check attacks on "secret" strings with a one-way function. The exception to my rule of thumb is securely generated random bits. (The equivalent of at least 96 bits and not generated by a third party.) Your clarification partly invalidates my answer, but I still wouldn't have been comfortable giving the opposite answer had I known that

Comment: @RanjitMurali In this case, offline cracking (hashing with a known HMAC key) might be easier for targeted victims. Someone may be able to find the last four or five PAN digits printed on a person's receipt. Or attached to someone's Amazon account. The leading digits might be revealed for similar reasons.

Comment: Also... Despite my rule saying "treat hashes as if they were plaintext", that doesn't necessarily mean abandon hashing, If it's a choice between storing plaintexts or hashes, then choose hashing. Always choose hashing if all that's necessary is to test for equality. Don't store more data than you need to. (And with that, that's all I can offer because I'm not qualified to interpret policy.)